# apply patchs for linux kernel in terminal with question mark

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, debian

I want to build `linux-rt` kernel and after downloading `kernel` and `patch` from `kernel.org` website i run this command as with documentation:

```
gzip -cd ../patch-5.11.4-rt11.patch.gz | patch -p1 --verbose {}
```

now i see this line in first time

```
patching file {}
Using Plan A...
Hunk #1 FAILED at 35.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file {}.rej
Hmm...  The next patch looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/include/linux/rbtree.h b/include/linux/rbtree.h
|index d7db179963221..c33b0e16d04b4 100644
|--- a/include/linux/rbtree.h
|+++ b/include/linux/rbtree.h
--------------------------
patching file {}
Using Plan A...
Hunk #1 FAILED at 19.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 112.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file {}.rej
Hmm...The next patch would create the file {},
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
```

which key should be pressed to apply this patches ?

Comment: Without seeing why that patch was rejected its impossible to say.  Are you sure that patch matches the version and doesn't require prior patches?

Comment: @stark i download both of `patch-5.11.4-rt11.patch.gz` and `linux-5.11.tar.gz`, Aren't the same together? could you help me witch patch should me get?

Comment: I guess you need `linux-5.11.4.tar.gz`. Also, you have `cd`ed to the `linux-5.4.11` directory before running `patch -p1`, right?

Comment: Also, it appears to be trying to patch a file called `{}`. You should remove that `{}` from the command line.